# хороший пинг из разных стран - что искать?

Tags: сервер, hosting, ping

Добрый день.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Нужно, чтобы сервер сайта одинаково хорошо пинговался из разных регионов. Россия и Азия (разные точки).

Куда смотреть и как это вообще реализовать, что хотя бы гуглить?)
Смотрел CDN, но это только скорость отдачи контента. А если до сервера коннект 3 секунды идет, чтобы увидеть html со ссылками на cdn, то это уже не спасет. Понятно, что сам html тоже может быть в cdn. Но есть же еще бд, php итд.

Может быть можно несколько хостингов взять, но как тогда настроить, чтобы от локации именно на нужный шел? заранее спасибо за любую наводку

Comment: Крупные хостинги позволяют разместить зеркала в разных регионах и направляют клиентов к ближайшему. Например, AWS.

Answer (score 1):

CDN -  это content delivery network  (система **доставки** контента).

Все сети cdn имеют множество серверов в разных частях света, как раз для минимизации ping.

Не надо изобретать велосипед и ставить свои сервера в Париже и Пекине. Все уже сделано.

На сайтах cdn есть карты размещения серверов.